# How to use google-libphonenumber in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

Requirement is I want to format phone number which is present on Contact record and based on User's locale I want to format the phone number in local as well as international format based on User's country.

e.g. If Country Code is **IN** and Number is **1234567890** and If User's locale is **China(CH)** then it should format the phone as **00 91 12345 67890** as per below demo link :

http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/

I am trying to use below library and uploaded as Static Resource JS file and call it in LWC as below:

https://github.com/ruimarinho/google-libphonenumber

LWC JS:

```
import {
    LightningElement
} from 'lwc';
import phoneUtil from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/libphonenumber';
import {
    loadScript
} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
export default class HiabPhoneNumberValidation extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, phoneUtil)
            .then(() => console.log('Loaded sayHello'))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connectedCallback')
    }
    handleClick(){
        const utils = phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US'), 'US');
        console.log('phoneUtil'+JSON.stringify(utils));
    }
}
```

When I try to click on button then I am getting an error message :

**[i.default.parse is not a function]**

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

The line
`import phoneUtil from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/libphonenumber';` defines phoneUtil as a string containing the url of the static resource. This string does not have a `parse()` function nor a `isValidNumberForRegion()` function, so `const utils = phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US'), 'US');` won't work.

Comment: Ok but could you please tell me how can I use this file in LWC? It's a JS file that I updated in Static Resource "libphonenumber" and Actual JS file that I am uploading is "libphonenumber.js"

Comment: I never used libphonenumber so I can't help you there, but google provides a javascript demo for usage of the libary at https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo.js

Comment: There is a loadscript call here that loads the static resource content as JavaScript into the LWC content. Note, however, that loaded scripts do have to be straight forward JavaScript, not modules, and that they actually end up being wrapped. Check the loadscript docs and the lib's API docs.

Comment: @PhilW Did check the doc but its difficult to figure out how to implement the same in LWC. If you have used this library earlier, do share some information.